# Is there a chrome switch to suppress 'external protocol request'?

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

Is there a chrome switch to suppress 'external protocol request' ?

I am automating an application using selenium - ruby - watir webdriver.

I searched over net for solutions to bypass this window and conversation: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/K22hXwRy6zQ 
gives an overview on how we can do that manually. But for Selenium-Chrome-Ruby, I need to do this by probably setting a chrome switch (List of chorme switch:= http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc). and that's a huge list.  I need help with figuring out which switch would probably help me bypass external protocol request window or if there is any workaround for this through automation?

Comment: could you better describe why you need to do this?  considering you leave selenium's control once you leave that window, not sure why your test should suppress it. your test should be "make sure it appears."

Comment: External protocol request chrome dialog will only stop automation to proceed further. I cannot use selenium to handle it since it is not part of webpage. I can use AutoIt but I don't want to do that because its just a overhead to automation script to handle it every time it is observed. I don't want to worry about this window atleast for a specific protocol I am sure is not harmful.  
So if there is a automation way (chrome switch or a registry setting) that I could use to supress this window would help.

Comment: have you found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/K22hXwRy6zQ has given the answer already, what we should do is change the `prefs` for watir browser

codes as below:

```rb
prefs = {
    protocol_handler: {
        excluded_schemes: {
            your_scheme: true,
        }
    },
}

Watir::Browser.new :chrome, prefs: prefs
```

Thanks for your research @simminni