# Protractor doesn't recognize opened native alert

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, alert

I'm trying to handle a native opened alert but protractor doesn't recognize this alert and send an error to console -

> 1) Test cases pull - LiveSite - Call
>          Message:
>            NoSuchAlertError: no alert open
>         (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.103)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Windows NT 10.0
>   x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information)
>       Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
>       Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
>       System info: host: 'vCitaQA', ip: '10.0.0.5', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
>       Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>       Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false,
>   chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\idan\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir3336_20019},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   version=51.0.2704.103, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false,
>   nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
>       Session ID: 96c8dfa136495b599f607d50616468de
>          Stacktrace:
>            NoSuchAlertError: no alert open
>         (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.103)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Windows NT 10.0
>   x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information)
>       Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
>       Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
>       System info: host: 'vCitaQA', ip: '10.0.0.5', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
>       Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>       Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false,
>   chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\idan\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir3336_20019},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   version=51.0.2704.103, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false,
>   nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
>       Session ID: 96c8dfa136495b599f607d50616468de
>           at new bot.Error (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113:18)
>           at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\response.js:106:9)
>           at C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:377:20
>           at [object Object].promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1877:20)
>           at [object Object].promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:2464:25)
>           at [object Object].promise.Promise.notify_ (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:563:12)
>           at Array.forEach (native)
>           at Object.goog.array.forEach (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\array\array.js:203:43)
>           at [object Object].promise.Promise.notifyAll_ (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:552:16)
>           at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:125:21)
>       From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
>           at [object Object]. (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:93:33)
>           at [object Object]. (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\async-callback.js:45:37)
>           at [object Object].jasmine.Block.execute (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:1174:17)
>           at [object Object].jasmine.Queue.next_ (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2209:31)
>           at [object Object]._onTimeout (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2199:18)
>       Error
>           at [object Object]. (c:\automation\tests\testCases\newApp\livesiteClient.js:74:3)
>           at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe_ (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:913:21)
>           at [object Object].jasmine.Env.describe (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:898:15)
>           at describe (C:\automation\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27)
>           at Object. (c:\automation\tests\testCases\newApp\livesiteClient.js:1:63)

I've already tried to use -

```
 describe('vCita Production - Livesite (client side)', function() {

   var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
   var callBtn = $$('div.action-content.layout-align-center.layout-column.flex').get(1); 

      beforeEach(function() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
      });

      afterEach(function() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
      });

  it('click on call button', function() {
    callBtn.click().then(function(){
      browser.driver.sleep(2000);
      browser.driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
    });
  });
});
```

And also the code below (that's actually works but it just ignore the alret and doesn't get into the "(alert)" if statement -

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {      
    browser.switchTo().window(handles[handles.length - 1]);
    var alertDialog = browser.switchTo().alert().thenCatch(function (e) {
        if (e.code !== 27) { throw e; }
    }).then(function (alert) {
        if (alert) {
            expect(alertDialog.getText()).toEqual("External Protocol Request");
            return alert.dismiss();
        }

callBtn.click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, this is the "External Protocol Request" dialog - *it is not a native alert* and is a browser/system dialog which *cannot be controlled from the Protractor/Selenium side*. Here are the relevant threads with some additional information in case of `chrome`:

- [Bypass "External protocol request" popup during selenium automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554564/bypass-external-protocol-request-popup-during-selenium-automation)
- [Is there a chrome switch to suppress 'external protocol request'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034715/is-there-a-chrome-switch-to-suppress-external-protocol-request)

In case of Firefox, things might be simpler. The idea is to:

- first manually open Firefox, click the "call" button and choose the default application
- go to "Help"->"Troubleshooting information" and click the button in the "Profile Folder" row
- copy the path to the profile directory and [start protractor+firefox with this profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873378/set-firefox-profile-with-protractor)

Comment: @IdanE does it fail with a timeout exception? Do you see the alert opened during the test run? Are you sure this is a native alert? Thanks.

Comment: @IdanE ah, you mean the "external protocol request" dialog? If yes, I know what is this about.

Comment: Yes, I meant for this dialog, great!